# EventHub Trigger funtion using python

Tags: web-applications, storage, python-3.6, azure-eventhub, azure-function-app

Hope you are doing good.

I need your help on basic setup for azure function using python to get the event Hub string data and push the telemetry simultaneously to the storage and web app as well. thanks

Comment: Suppose the official doc could help you and you should post your question not just ask help without topic.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=python

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions EventHub Trigger Python Sample that read message from  EventHub that sent from sender and write an output record to Azure Table Storage using Azure Table bindings.

**function.json**

```html
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "myEventHubMessage",
      "path": "<eventhub-entitiy-name>",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default",
      "connection": "<eventhub-namespace>_<SAS-policy-name>_EVENTHUB",
      "cardinality": "one",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "name": "outputTable",
      "tableName": "<table-name>",
      "connection": "<storage-account-name>_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

**run.py**

```html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import json
import uuid

"""
Expected Receiving Body Message:
{
    "deviceId": "myDevice0001",
    "temperature": "10.1"
}
[note]
Use "deviceId" as PartitionKey for Azure table to write
Expected Function's Trigger Configuration:
 - 'trigger': AzureEventHub
 - 'Event hub cardinality': 'One'
Expected Function's Output Configuration:
 - 'output': Azure Table Storage
 - 'Table parameter name: 'outputTable
"""

# Read the EventHub Message 
receivedBody = json.loads(open(os.environ['myEventHubMessage']).read())
print('Received body:', receivedBody)
# -> ('received object:', {u'deviceId': u'myDevice0001', u'temperature': u'10.1'})
if not 'deviceId' in receivedBody or not 'temperature' in receivedBody:
    print("Skip: invalid eventHub body!")
    sys.exit(0)

## Device ID
recordId = str(uuid.uuid4())

outdoc= {
    "PartitionKey": receivedBody['deviceId'], 
    "RowKey": recordId,
    "temperature": receivedBody['temperature']
}
# Writing to Azure Table Storage (Table parameter name: outputTable)
print('Writing data to Azure Table:', outdoc)
with open(os.environ['outputTable'], 'w') as f:
    json.dump(outdoc,f)
```

Complete sample can be found on **https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/tree/master/v1functions/eventhub-trigger-table-out-bindings**